# How long do Channel Divinity effects last?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, cleric, paladin

What's the duration of Channel Divinity effects?

Comment: I think the meta on "[read the manual](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/4825/23970)" is more on point: it discusses why an on-topic extremely-low complexity question might be deserving of downvotes but *not* closure. I'm voting to reopen, as it's perfectly clear what OP's asking: a super-simple question.

Answer (score 8):

The description of the particular option tells you.

#### Many are "instants":

Destructive Wrath, Guided Strike, Preserve Life, Radiance of the Dawn, Turn the Tide, War God's Blessing

#### Until the end of your next turn:

Cloak of Shadows

#### 1-minute duration (though some have other end-triggers, such as taking damage or a repeated save):

Abjure Enemy, Arcane Abjuration, Charm Animals/Plants, Invoke Duplicity, Read Thoughts, Sacred Weapon, Turn Faithless/Undead/Unholy, Vow of Enmity

#### 10-minute duration (ditto):

Knowledge of the Ages

#### Until successful save:

Nature's Wrath

#### Until incapacitated/dead/forcibly removed from area:

Champion's Challenge